# Making a div inline with <p> tag

Tags: html

For my website, I've been wanting to add a Facebook Follow button.
I want it to look something like this:

Follow us on Facebook: [THE FOLLOW BUTTON]

Note that the <p> tag and the <div> tag of the button should be inline.

I'm using the following code:

```
<p>Follow us on Facebook:</p><div id="follow-button"></div>
```

When using the code, it's not rendering properly and the Follow button is always displayed below the <p> tag

Comment: `<p>` and `<div>` are both block elements. Use something else. Why not two spans?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make both elements inline:

Your html:

```
<p> Follow us on Facebook: </p>
<div id="follow-button"> Button </div>
```

Your css:

```
p { display: inline; }
div { display: inline; }
```

(Note you can also set them to 'inline-block' if you want them to act like block elements)

Answer (score 1):

change your code as below:

```
<p style="display:inline-block;">Follow us on Facebook:</p><div style="display:inline-block;" id="follow-button">btn</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because `<div`> always take 100% width. Why don't you take `<button>` in place of `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

you  can use this single line code

```
<p style="display:inline"> follow us on <div id="follow-button"    style="display:inline"> Button </div> </p>
```